# Windows synchronization on multiple mutexes

Tags: c++, winapi, synchronization, mutex, waitformultipleobjects

I'm not clear about this, can someone confirm this for me?

I have the following synchronization issue. I have the following objects:

```
A. Process 1, thread 1: Read & write access to the resource.
B. Process 1, thread 2: Read access to the resource.
C. Process 2, thread 3: Read access to the resource.
```

And here's the access conditions:

1. A must be blocked while B or C are on.
2. B must be blocked only while A is on.
3. C must be blocked only while A is on.

So I thought to use 2 named mutexes for that:

- hMutex2 = used to satisfy condition 2 above.
- hMutex3 = used to satisfy condition 3 above.
- hStopEvent = a stop event (needs to stop the thread if the app is closing).

So for A:

```
HANDLE hHandles[3] = {hMutex2, hMutex3, hStopEvent};
DWORD dwRes = WaitForMultipleObjects(3, hHandles, FALSE, INFINITE);
if(dwRes == WAIT_OBJECT_0 + 2)
{
    //Quit now
    return;
}
else if(dwRes == WAIT_OBJECT_0 + 0 ||
    dwRes == WAIT_OBJECT_0 + 1)
{
    //Do reading & writing here
    ...

    //Release ownership
    ReleaseMutex(hMutex2);
    ReleaseMutex(hMutex3);
}
else
{
    //Error
}
```

For B:

```
DWORD dwRes = WaitForSingleObject(hMutex2, INFINITE);
if(dwRes == WAIT_OBJECT_0)
{
    //Do reading here
    ...

    //Release ownership
    ReleaseMutex(hMutex2);
}
else
{
    //Error
}
```

For C:

```
DWORD dwRes = WaitForSingleObject(hMutex3, INFINITE);
if(dwRes == WAIT_OBJECT_0)
{
    //Do reading here
    ...

    //Release ownership
    ReleaseMutex(hMutex3);
}
else
{
    //Error
}
```

Can someone confirm this:

- When calling WaitForMultipleObjects on both mutexes, do they both become signaled (or blocked)?
- Also do I needs to release both mutexes?

Comment: You want a "reader writer" lock. And if memory serves, it can be done without WaitForMultipleObjects. (You'll likely need WaitFSO). I'll see if I can dig up an implementation of that later today.  Until then Bing for "reader writer lock"

Answer (score 2):

The [WaitForMultipleObjects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687025%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) call as written (FALSE for the 3rd parameter) will return when any one of the mutexes is signaled.  This means that both the writer and one of the readers could obtain simultaneous access to the resource. One reader could be accessing the resource while the other reader releases its mutex.  At that point, the writer would be released.

So to use both mutexes like that, you would need to wait on both of them.  However, you cannot just set that third parameter to TRUE since it would mean that it would require hStopEvent to also be signaled in order to release that thread (which is obviously not desired).

One possibility might be to check which mutex was released and then have the writer wait for the other one as well before continuing.  Then it would need to release both of them after finishing its task. A problem with this type of solution is that it can start getting complex in a hurry and if you add more processes that need the mutexes, you can end up with deadlock if you are not careful. Using a reader-writer type of lock would simplify the processing quite a bit.

**Edit** This is not really part of the answer to the question, but depending on the processes involved and how often they will access the resource and how long they will hold the mutex while accessing it, you could really simplify it by using one mutex and just treating it as a critical section ... each process gets it when it needs access to the resource.  It of course would not allow both reader threads/processes to have concurrent access, though, so that may or may not be acceptable.  But it is a lot easier to verify in the long run.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. It all makes sense. I guess now I'll try to search for "reader writer lock" for WinAPIs. I'm glad I posted it here before I began implementing it...

Comment: I would assume there are some available, but I don't have a recommendation. I ended up writing a reader-writer lock for C based on a presentation I attended by Jeffrey Richter.  It was probably stupid to write my own, but it has been peer reviewed by my co-workers and in use for maybe 10 years ... so I think it is working. I wouldn't recommend writing your own, though.  It is really easy to get it wrong.  I was not able to find one publicly available then that would work on the three different OS's I had to deal with at the time.

Comment: In my case the reads are happening way more often than writes, thus it will really slow things down if I just use a single mutex for all of them. As for finding an implementation for this read-write-lock, all I keep getting is when they use critical sections and have no way of stopping waiting threads with my stop-event approach.

Answer (score 0):

As a matter of fact, I can contradict it.  `WaitForMultipleObjects` with the `waitAll` parameter set to `FALSE` will return if *any* of the objects are signaled.  [Here's the documentation :)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687025%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)  Set it to `TRUE` and you'll have it waiting for *all* objects.

Your solution **doesn't scale well**, though: add another reading thread, and you're stuck with a third mutex...

The [Writer/Readers problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Readers%E2%80%93writer_lock) has been solved many times before, however; why not take a look into **existing implementations**?  Will save you a lot of debug time, especially if you're not yet familiar with the windows synchronization API.  (Teaser: posix threads have a readwritelock, boost has a `shared_mutex`.)

Comment: As noted by Mark's comment, setting to `TRUE` doesn't work because that would also wait for `hStopEvent`.

Comment: @RaymondChen: indeed; 'what you want' is somewhat over-optimistic, I admit :)

Comment: So any idea which WinAPIs to use for that reader writer lock?

Comment: Personally: no experience.  Boost has an interprocess library that contains mutexes: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/interprocess/synchronization_mechanisms.html#interprocess.synchronization_mechanisms.mutexes

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is reader-writer lock. In your algorithm there is one serious problem - starvation of process A: if B and C keeps working and taking their mutexes, A might be unable to enter.